# counting the number of radio buttons checked and displaying the value in a textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

my webform is a questionniare and it contains 10 pairs of radio buttons with yes or no options , i want the user to answer all the 10 questions and display number of yes and no in two separate textboxes. kindly help me with this

Thanking you

Comment: This site is not a code factory. What have you done so far?

Comment: DO yo want to display number of yes and nos as user selects, or only after your form is submitted?

Comment: yes after the user clicked the submit button

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to do this but I would just define a PositiveAnswer and NegativeAnswer variable and increment each when a Yes or No answer is chosen for each radio button.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign a class say "yes" to all radiobuttons for Yes and a class "no" to all radiobuttons for no. Then using jquery you can find the count as follows:

```
var totalYesAnswers = $(".yes :checked").length;
var totalNoAnswers = $(".no :checked").length;
```